# Speed test library in React Native

Tags: android, library, api, react

I'm trying to create a mobile app in React Native that measures the download and upload speed from a server, similar to how Ookla Speedtest, but it'll measure the speed on the network, not on Wifi.

I found a speedtest node module on GitHub called [speedtest.net](https://github.com/ddsol/speedtest.net) and I tried to implement it into my React Native project, but haven't had much luck. So I was wondering if anyone knew other speed test libraries in React Native that I could use to get the upload and download speed from a server? Does anyone have any suggestions?